# Repeat value infinitely Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

For zipping, how can I zip a list with repetitions of a single value?

desired:

```js
R.zip([1, 2, 3])(R.repeat(2)); // [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `map`? `R.map(e => [e, 2], [1, 2, 3]);`

Comment: Ramda doesn't create or understand lazy lists that you might use in, say, Haskell.  So while you could predefine a finite repeated list as doe the answer from user19461620, I think mapping, as Konrad notes is not only more efficient, but also more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`R.ap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) as a combinator of the `R.zip` function and a function that takes the length, and repeats and item:

```js
const { ap, zip, pipe, length, repeat } = R

const fn = item => ap(
  zip,
  pipe(length, repeat(item))
)

const result = fn(2)([1, 2, 3])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

This an overkill, but just for the sake of completeness - you can create Infinite lazy arrays in JS using a proxy. Create an array proxy with a `get` trap. For length return `Infinity`, and call a cb function to generate an item. In this case I use `R.always` to create always return 2 for an item:

```js
const { zip, __, always } = R

const getInfiniteArray = getItem => new Proxy([], {
  get(target, prop, receive) {
    return prop === 'length' 
      ? Infinity
      : getItem(target, prop, receive)
  }
})

const fn = zip(__, getInfiniteArray(always(2)))

const result = fn()([1, 2, 3])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Comments especially Scott's help me understand that this clearly isn't the right way to think when using Ramda, but this is the best "workaround solution to the question as asked

Comment: @minseong - I've added an example with a lazy infinite array using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
R.zip([1, 2, 3], R.repeat(2, 3));
```

Comment: I gues that op doesn't know the size of the first array

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out, Ramda doesn't understand lazy lists, mainly because javascript does not provide support for lazy evaluation...

Probably this is the closest you could get, ramda would play a minimal role here though:

```js
function* infiniteZipWith(fn) {
  let number = 0;
  
  while (true) {
    yield [++number, fn()];
  }
};

const list = infiniteZipWith(R.always(2));

console.log(list.next().value);
console.log(list.next().value);
console.log(list.next().value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: isn't a generator literally lazy evaluation? What do you mean by saying javascript doesn't support lazy evaluation?

Comment: generators are the closest thing, but first class lazy evaluation is more something on these lines https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation where expressions are not immediately evaluated as soon as they're bound to variable, but only when they're needed by other computations. Reading about thunks can also help (https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk)